# undefined reference error while installing OpenCV not compiling

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to find the same case as mine, but I couldn't. Most of them here are about undefined reference error during compiling their own code, but in my case this error occurred while installing OpenCV.

I referred to this page :
http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/

I use armv7l and debian-scratch 9.3.
I tried to install OpenCV 3.4.0

I have this error :

```
[ 31%] Building CXX object modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_features2d.dir/src/akaze.cpp.o
//usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined reference to `XML_SetUserData'
//usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined reference to `XML_SetUnknownEncodingHandler'
//usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined reference to `FT_Set_Char_Size'
//usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `glGenerateMipmap'
//usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `glUniform2fv'
//usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libbluray.so.1: undefined reference to `FT_GlyphSlot_Embolden'

...

//usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `deflateReset'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../bin/opencv_annotation: hidden symbol `atexit' in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc_nonshared.a(atexit.oS) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
apps/annotation/CMakeFiles/opencv_annotation.dir/build.make:100: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_annotation' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_annotation] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4690: recipe for target 'apps/annotation/CMakeFiles/opencv_annotation.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [apps/annotation/CMakeFiles/opencv_annotation.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I found out it's from a linking library error, but as I'm a beginner of Linux, it couldn't help me.
I hope this question is clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @Biffen thank you for the information. But I'm installing OpenCV not doing compiling my code. Would that be the same thing as in my situation?